# Asymptotics for some modified Bessel function of first kind

Tags: asymptotics, bessel-functions

I am interested in the asymptotics for large order and large argument for the modified Bessel function of first kind
$$I_{\frac{N-1}{2}} (Nz) $$
where

- $z$ is a fixed positive real number $z>0$ and
- $N$ is natural number.

I want to pass $N$ to $+\infty$.
I checked the NIST collection and the book by Abramowitz and Stegun, but I did not find anything useful. Do you have any tips? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\kappa \in \mathbb C$ be fixed, $x>0$ and $\operatorname{Re}(\nu)>0$. By [$(10.32.12)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E12), we can write
$$
I_{\nu  + \kappa } (\nu \operatorname{csch} x) = \frac{1}{{2\pi {\rm i}}}\int_{\infty  - {\rm i}\pi }^{\infty  + {\rm i}\pi } {\exp \left( { - \nu (t - \operatorname{csch} x\cosh t)} \right)\,{\rm e}^{ - \kappa t} {\rm d}t} .
$$
The relevant saddle point is at $t=x$. An application of the [saddle point method](http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.4.iv) then gives
$$
I_{\nu  + \kappa } (\nu \operatorname{csch}x) \sim \frac{{\exp (\nu (\coth x - x) - \kappa x)}}{{\sqrt {2\pi \nu \coth x} }}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{U^{\kappa}_n (\tanh x)}}{{\nu ^n }}} ,
$$
as $\nu \to \infty$ in the sector $|\arg \nu|\le \frac{\pi}{2}-\delta<\frac{\pi}{2}$, uniformly with respect to $x>0$ (cf. [$(10.41.3)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.41.E3)). The coefficients $U^{\kappa}_n(w)$ are polynomials in $w$ of degree $3n$, the first few being
\begin{align*}
& U^{\kappa}_0(w)=1,\\
& U^{\kappa}_1(w)= - \frac{5}{{24}}w^3  - \frac{\kappa }{2}w^2  + \frac{{1 - 4\kappa ^2 }}{8}w,
\\& U^{\kappa}_2(w)=\frac{{385}}{{1152}}w^6  + \frac{{35\kappa }}{{48}}w^5  + \frac{{7(20\kappa ^2  - 11)}}{{192}}w^4  + \frac{{\kappa (20\kappa ^2  - 29)}}{{48}}w^3  + \frac{{16\kappa ^4  - 40\kappa ^2  + 9}}{{128}}w^2 .
\end{align*}
In general,
$$
U^{\kappa}_n(w) = \frac{{( - w)^n }}{{2^n n!}}\left[ {\frac{{{\rm d}^{2n} }}{{{\rm d}t^{2n} }}\left( {{\rm e}^{ - \kappa t} \left( {\frac{1}{2}\frac{{t^2 }}{{\cosh t - 1 + w(\sinh t - t)}}} \right)^{n + 1/2} } \right)} \right]_{t = 0} .
$$
In [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jat.2021.105562), the following recurrence was established:
$$
U_{n + 1}^\kappa  (w) =  - \kappa w^2 U_n^\kappa  (w) + \frac{1}{2}w^2 (1 - w^2 )\frac{{{\rm d}U_n^\kappa  (w)}}{{{\rm d}w}} + \frac{1}{8}\int_0^w {(1 - 4\kappa ^2  + 8\kappa t - 5t^2 )U_n^\kappa  (t){\rm d}t} 
$$
for $n\ge 0$, with initial value $U^{\kappa}_0(w)=1$.

In your case $\nu  = \frac{N}{2}$, $x = \operatorname{csch}^{ - 1} (2z)$, and $\kappa  =  - \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems to be useful.